# Encrypting data by OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY by ASYMMETRIC KEY created with Azure provider in SQL server takes more than 2 min

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure

Have created a SYMMETRIC KEY for decryption by ASYMMETRIC KEY and the ASYMMETRIC KEY is created with Azure keyvault based key provider. Have used the details provided from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/setup-steps-for-extensible-key-management-using-the-azure-key-vault?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=portal) and [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/azure-key-vault-integration-configure?view=azuresql)

Have used the 'SQL Server Connector for Microsoft Azure Key Vault' and then created a credential with the Azure Key Vault identity.
Created an ASYMMETRIC KEY with the key present on the Azure Key Vault
Created a SYMMETRIC KEY

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY DATA_ENCRYPTION_KEY
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY CONTOSO_KEY;
```

In a stored procedure i am opening the Symmetric key.

```
--Open the symmetric key for use in this session
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY DATA_ENCRYPTION_KEY
DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY CONTOSO_KEY;

SELECT @DATA = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('DATA_ENCRYPTION_KEY'), CONVERT(VARBINARY, @xmlString));
 INSERT INTO MYTable
 (
    Data
 )
 Value
(
  @DATA
)
--Close the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY DATA_ENCRYPTION_KEY;
```

When I call this stored procedure form code with the ExecuteDataSet I get a timeout error with SQL execution. As soon i run the same SP on DB once and a session is created the next requests work fine until the session is active, and then the timeout occurs again.

When I run the stored procedure form the SQL Mangement studio, the query execution completes in 2:15 min. I added form tracing to capture timings and I see that the `'OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY'` takes up all the time. If you see the table below between the first log entry to second where it opens the key it takes more than 2 min

```
Id           Message                        time
**84        messages created               2022-11-16 15:13:09.027
84          opened symmetric key           2022-11-16 15:15:24.463**
84          encrypted with symmetric key   2022-11-16 15:15:24.467
84          encrypted data inserted        2022-11-16 15:15:24.470
84          Closed symmetric key           2022-11-16 15:15:24.470
```

Comment: The post is missing many data points. 1) What's the error? 2) What's in the errorlog? 3) What's in the application logs for akv? 4) What's in the system errorlogs?

Comment: Are you running this on Azure SQL Database or is the database a SQL Server database on your laptop?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani it is a SQL server database on Azure hosted Virtual machine.

Comment: I think it's like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105290/decryptbykey-slower-on-sql-server-2014-than-sql-server-2012 . It myght depend by the SQL Server version you are on and SP can be sometimes slow. Good luck debugging that but I don't think there's much you can change