# OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY from AKV takes too long randomly

Tags: sql-server, encryption, azure, symmetric-key

This post is similar to another question listed here. [Encrypting data by OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY by ASYMMETRIC KEY created with Azure provider in SQL server takes more than 2 min](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319755/encrypting-data-by-open-symmetric-key-by-asymmetric-key-created-with-azure-provi)

We are also facing the similar problem on our PROD server randomly, did anyone find a fix for this one. Below is the SQL statement we are executing with timestamp, randomly the time taken between the statement print 'before open ....' and print 'after open ....' is more than a minute and at a time is less than a second.

```
print 'before open ' + convert(varchar(50),getdate(),114)

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SYMMETRIC_KEY_NAME BY ASYMMETRIC KEY ASYMMETRIC_KEY_MECHANISM;

print 'after open ' + convert(varchar(50),getdate(),114)

-- SQL Select query

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SYMMETRIC_KEY_NAME 

print 'after close ' + convert(varchar(50),getdate())
```

[image]

Few findings from our end.

There is no error reported, just a continous info logged in eventviewer

> The description for Event ID 0 from source SQL Server Connector for
> Microsoft Azure Key Vault cannot be found. Either the component that
> raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the
> installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on
> the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
> had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Vault Name: vaultname.vault.azure.net Operation: Constructor Key Name:
> Message: [error:0, info:0, state:0] The Operation was successful.
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
> string/message table

There are outbound network calls in firewall logs which connects to Microsoft Azure, and there are continous denials (resets) from Microsoft.
The same setup works on our lower Test environment, just PROD is affected.
Already raised this issue in another forum. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275244/sql-decryption-randomly-slow?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1245040#newest-answer-comment

Comment: Welcome to DBA. I think its the same as the other post. Duplicate questions tend to get closed

Comment: What are the URIs for the resets? What is the longest response (including successful) for a conversation? Are the CRL endpoints allowed to be contacted through the firewall? etc.

Comment: @SeanGallardy: We have IP 20.62.134.228 that restting us.

Comment: That doesn't help anyone here, we don't have any traces, we don't have any information other than what you provide.

Comment: @SeanGallardy: This info from packet tracer may be of help.
[No.]25 [Time]131.085490 [Source]20.62.134.228 [Destination]10.20.36.150 [Protocol]TCP [Length]58 [Info]443 → 57108 [RST, ACK] Seq=7779 Ack=2735 Win=0 Len=0